# How to install LXC (or other linux container) on centOS 5 (2.6.18 kernel) without modify kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, virtual-machine, lxc

[Background]

I would like to regulate the resource allocation between different processes running on CentOS 5. I am not familiar with related tools. I have searched for a while and think LXC may be a good choice (Please correct me if I am wrong). But the problem is that the kernel version of our CentOS is 2.6.18, which does not have LXC built in. And it is a shared cluster. I do have sudo authority but I am not allowed to modify the kernel. The tutorials I found all require to modify the kernel or recompile it somehow.

[Question]

How can I install and use LXC (or other light weight linux virtualization tools) on CentOS 5 (2.6.18 kernel) without modify the kernel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to install it without changing the kernel, someone will have had to back-port it to the 2.6.18 EL5 kernel, and compile it as a kernel module.

Assuming you have a recent CentOS EL5 kernel, KVM is a good option as it's a kernel module and doesn't require a kernel change, like xen does. You just have to have hardware that supports virtualization.

Comment: Hi, is the KVM a full virtualization solution that emulates everything? Basically what we need is just regulating the CPU and memory allocation between different processes. And it is good if we can migrate the processes from one physical server to another. Any recommendation? Thank you!

Comment: KVM is a full virtualization solution. I haven't used it much, so I can't speak for it's ability to migrate to other physical servers. I do know that Xen can do it. But in either case, you need shared disk between the two hosts if you want to migrate a VM from one host to another.